# converting Lighttpd rule to apache rules

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, url, mediawiki

I am using mediawiki on my localhost server. my url for now is 127.0.0.1:8080/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

But i want to convert above mentioned url to wiki.127.0.0.1:8080 or something like wiki.nikunj.com if my wiki is url is www.nikunj.com/wiki

I read this article http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL but not able to achieve it.

They have given how to convert www.example.com to wiki.example.com but using Lighthttpd.

here is the code:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "wiki.example.com" {
server.document-root = "/path/to/webroot"
url.rewrite-once = (
"(^/[^:]*[\./].*)" => "$1",
"^/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))?" => "/w/index.php?title=$1&$2",
)
}
```

Also i have a website like www.nikunj.com.
There i installed wiki to www.nikunj.com/wiki, now i want to port it to wiki.nikunj.com

I tried this but it doesn't worked.

With mod_rewrite:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName wiki.nikunj.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.nikunj.com/wiki/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

With mod_alias:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName wiki.nikunj.com
RedirectMatch ^/(.*) http://www.nikunj.com/wiki/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

But is is not working please, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Lighthttpd url.rewrite-once rewrites URLs internally.  The Apache configuration code you proposed would serve to redirect, in both cases.

For explanation of lighttpd code:
http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite#urlrewrite-once

You actually do not need to do anything special to use wiki.nikunj.com instead of nikunj.com .
Simply use the ServerName and DocumentRoot directives like for any VirtualHost.

If your MediaWiki files live at /path/to/webroot/wiki, then your DocumentRoot directive would read like the example below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName wiki.nikunj.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/webroot/wiki
</VirtualHost>
```

+++++

You will also need to add MediaWiki's suggested Apache rewrite code:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache

With the above code, where wiki.nikunj.com uses /path/to/webroot/wiki , you will need to include this rewrite code, either in
/path/to/webroot/wiki/.htaccess or in the above VirtualHost block.

```
## http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/*$ /index.php [L]
```